# How to delete shortest matched pattern from the end of string by re module of python?

Tags: python, bash

I am converting my bash code to python code.

Now I would like to make a function which has same functionality of ${variable%pattern} in bash; which delete shortest matched pattern from the end of the string,

For example, I expect delete_tail('_usr_home_you_file.ext.tar.oz', r'.') results in '_usr_home_you_file.ext.tar'

I made python function below,

```
import re

def delete_tail(word,pattern):
    return re.sub('{0}.*?$'.format(pattern), '', word)
```

However, it deletes longest matched pattern like following.

```
word='_usr_home_you_file.ext.tar.oz'
delete_shortest_match_tail=delete_tail(word,r'\.')
print("word = {0}".format(word))
print("delete_shortest_match_tail = {0}". format(delete_shortest_match_tail))
```

Output:

```
delete_shortest_match_tail = _usr_home_you_file
```

How can I make a function which deletes shortest matched pattern from the end of the string as I expected above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rather want to search for the string in front of the pattern rather than for the pattern to replace it. Regex always looks from left to right and all matches are reported in that order. We can't simply reverse the strings, because that would mess up the RegEx pattern. Because of that we can't use `sub`, but replacing something with an empty string is the same as deleting, OR **taking the rest of the string**. This is basically what this solution does. It searches for your result and simply omits the part you don't want.

```
def removeFromEnd(pattern, target):
  m = re.match("(.*)" + pattern + ".*$", target)
  if m:
    return m.group(0)
  else:
    return target
```

> >>> removeFromEnd("\.", "foo.tar.gz")
>
> 'foo.tar'

Comment: thank you for teaching me how to solve the problem. It worked. Please let me ask you two questions. (1) is it necessary to have ? in ".*?$". Both case, with or without '?' works in the same way for my case. (2) I could not understand why it is necessary to check len(m.groups()) > 0. I suppose it might be checked by m is not None. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mora you are right, both things are redundant and can be removed. I edited the answer. I have also simplified the condition and the retrieval of group 0.